# GeoFireStore where Query

Tags: reactjs, firebase, native, geofirestore

I have the following Firestore database. The data in this firestore was added
by geofirestore module https://github.com/geofirestore/geofirestore-js#example-usage.

How can i query this firestore using geofire Queries to find where  the field name="Sex"

Please search a solution for React native thanks.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d45B2.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably want to look at the [docs for future queries you may have](https://github.com/geofirestore/geofirestore-js#geofirestorequeryquerycriteria). However for the query you want it should be fairly simple...

```
// Create query listener

const geoQuery = geoFirestore.query({
  center: new firebase.firestore.GeoPoint(10.38, 2.41),
  radius: 10.5,
  query: (ref) => ref.where('d.details.name', '==', 'Sex')
});

// Then listen for results as they come in
const onKeyEnteredRegistration = geoQuery.on('key_entered', (key, document, distance) => {
  console.log(key + ' entered query at ' + document.coordinates.latitude + ',' + document.coordinates.longitude + ' (' + distance + ' km from center)');
});
```

Comment: Thanks sir :) I was able to figure it out:)

Answer (score 1):

Above answered query by @MichaelSolati,  works on the older version of GeoFireStore (2.x.x).
Here is how the same query on the version 3.x.x by Michael (taken from  [Github Issue](https://github.com/MichaelSolati/geofirestore-js/issues/136)).

```
const geocollection: GeoCollectionReference = geofirestore.collection('Users');
const geoQuery = geocollection.near({
    center: new firebase.firestore.GeoPoint(50.9235691,10.7218614),
    radius: 10.5
    }).where('d.details.name', '==', 'Sex');
```

Comment: it doesnt work with "bigger than"