# GeoFirestore - Is it possible to combine the methods near() and where() in a GeoQuery?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore, react-native-firebase, geofirestore

```js
 // Queries
 let query = geoCollection
    .where("status", "==", "active")
    .near({ center: new firebase.firestore.GeoPoint(latitude, longitude), radius: 1000 });

 // Subscribe, add jobs into store and listen for changes
 query.onSnapshot((res) => res.docs && Array.from(res.docs.map((doc) => console.log(doc.data()))));
```

When I perform the above it doesn't work properly.
but if I do this instead it works:

```
 let query = geoCollection.where("status", "==", "active")
```

or

```
let query = geoCollection.near({ center: new firebase.firestore.GeoPoint(latitude, longitude), radius: 1000 });
```

But not together! Which is what I want.

Here is the link for the Documentation. It's not very detailed, but I tried my best to look into the files and no luck so far.
https://firebaseopensource.com/projects/geofirestore/geofirestore-js/

Here is a picture of the structure:
[image]

Comment: I saw a few examples while researching a solution for your question, so it's definetelly possible, but one thing that I noticed is that every example uses `.near().where()` instead of the `where().near()` that you are using and this might be the case of why is not working, try making that change and let me know if it works.

Comment: @ralemos, thanks for assisting me. Anyway, It didn't work either. I look at one of the answer of this post, and it is exactly what you are saying near().where() https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53027146/geofirestore-where-query. But not luck. Also there is a method called query that it can combine both where and near at the same time but it looks like in the library this method is private. https://geofirestore.com/classes/_geoquery_.geoquery.html#firestore

Comment: I tried this: 
geoCollection.near({ center: new firebase.firestore.GeoPoint(latitude, longitude), radius: radius }).native.where("status", "==","active") but now ".native" is ignoring near()

Comment: "native" actually worked for me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally found a solution. It is required that you create an Index in the Cloud Firestore console.

1. Put your collection name in the first field in my case was "jobs"
2. Put the "where" property that you are comparing to in the field (Ascending)
3. Lastly, type `g.geohash` (Ascending)
4. Click Save, and wait around 5 and 10 minutes.

[image]

Comment: How is this even working? You cant have a  Where in Nearby query!

Comment: @showtime you are halfway right, geofirestore uses a range query. "[In a](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#limitations) compound query, range `<, <=, >, >=` and not equals `!=, not-in` comparisons must all filter on the same field." You can't have a range where query with a near query (that also uses range), but you can use a binary conditional like OP's "status".